# Is there a way to creat objects in a foreach loop out of an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, foreach

Im trying to make some buttons in a for each loop but i cant figure out how its right.
Does it even Work ?

```
        String[] myButtons = {"Label","Checkbox","CheckboxGroup", "Textfield", "TextArea","Choice", "List", "Scrollbar", "ScrolPane", "Ende"};

    for (String buttonName : myButtons) {
        Button buttonName = new Button( buttonName );
    }
```

Comment: You will need to more clearly state what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: You can add your button to a `JPanel` or `JFrame` by invoking the `.add()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if you don't try to reuse `buttonName`, then you'll be able to compile and create some buttons:

```
for (String buttonName : myButtons) {
    Button button = new Button( buttonName ); // right here!
}
```

But you're not doing anything with them. Maybe you want to add them to a frame?

```
for (String buttonName : myButtons) {
    Button button = new Button( buttonName );
    frame.add(button);
}
```

And are you sure you don't want to use `JButton`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're recreating the Button object with each pass. You only have a list of String names when you also need to instantiate a list of actual Button objects. Try this:

```
String[] buttonNames = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
Button[] buttons = new Button[buttonNames.length];
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   buttons[i] = new Button(buttonNames[i]);
}
```

Depending on what your Button object is, you could also include an anonymous function inside the for loop that would bind each button created to an event listener.